# 301 redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I had to change the link structure on my site, and to maintain my SEO value I'm trying to setup some 301 rules based on htaccess.

My old setup was this:

http://www.domain.com/news/23/some-text-here

My new setup is this:

http://www.domain.com/read/some-text-here

```
RewriteCond ^(news)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/read/$3 [L,R=301]
```

The method above gives me server an internal server error. I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for one, you're `RewriteCond` is missing a string to test against. The basic syntax is

```
RewriteCond TestString Pattern
```

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(news)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond
and also make sure the rewrite engine is enabled before anything else:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: I actually have this before the two lines I posted:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(news)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/read/$3 [L,R=301]

I'm having trouble filling the $3 - Can you possible tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I figured it out!. Thanks for your help